# “Ce n’est pas parce que A que B”: Is this sentence construction ambiguous by its very nature?

Tags: sens

> You don’t exactly take up learning Polish by finding their accents appealing...

To express this idea, the following sentence construction sprang to mind:

> ***Ce n’est pas parce qu***’on est attiré par l'accent polonais ***qu***’on se met à apprendre la langue...
>
> {I mean}: L'accent polonais, ce n’est pas vraiment ce qui nous incite à apprendre la langue...

But I wonder if this construction is ambiguous enough to give rise to two possible interpretations:

---

On one hand, if the "*ce n'est pas X que Y*" expression is intended, it will lead to the following interpretation (1):

> (There are various factors that may prompt you to take up learning Polish), but their accents are not one of them...

{... and this is exactly what I intended my French sentence to mean}

"*Ce n’est pas parce que A que B*" is interpreted as "***it's not because of A that you do B***".

---

On the other hand, if you consider the word "*pas*" to be negating the part "*qu’on se met ...*", it will lead to the other interpretation (2):

> You don't (necessarily) take up learning Polish just because you find their accents appealing...

{... here, it's taken as a given that Polish accents are appealing to you, but you'll need more incentive than that to actually commit yourself to learning Polish}

"*Ce n’est pas parce que A que B*" is interpreted as "***even if/though A is true, it doesn't mean B***".

Comment: I would solve the ambiguity by adding "seulement" in the sentence: "Ce n’est pas *seulement* parce qu’on est attiré par l'accent polonais qu’on se met à apprendre la langue."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ce n’est pas parce qu’on est attiré par l'accent polonais qu’on se met
>   à apprendre la langue.

Intuitively, in a vacuum, this reads as

> **Just because** you find the Polish accent appealing doesn't mean you're
>   going to want to learn Polish.

However, in spoken French, depending where the locutor puts the emphasis, it could mean *"it's certainly not the Polish accent that will make you..."*

It could also be the case with written French if the context wants it.

It is actually quite difficult to encapsulate that nuance in meaning in a single isolated sentence without a context. An additional adverb could help, such as

> On ne se met pas au polonais **simplement** parce que l'accent nous plait.

or for the alternate meaning,

> Ce n'est **certainement** pas l'accent polonais qui fait qu'on se met à apprendre la langue.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the sentence is ambiguous.

I would suggest:

> Ce n'est pas l'accent polonais qui peut inciter quelqu'un à apprendre cette langue.

Answer (score 0):

No, the sentence is not ambiguous at all.
« Ce n'est pas parce que *A* que *B* » = "*A* is not a reason to *B*", "We don't *B* because *A*". « Ce n'est pas parce que l'on est attiré par l'accent polonais que l'on apprend la langue » = « Notre attirance pour l'accent polonais ne fait pas partie des raisons pour lesquelles on veut apprendre la langue ».

Comment: Hi. So which of the two interpretations do you go with?

Comment: "(There are various factors that may prompt you to take up learning Polish), but their accents are not one of them…"

Comment: Thank you. Then I think I need to put forth a counter argument: ***« Ce n’est pas parce que j’habite à Paris que j’aime cette ville. »*** In this specific instance, the 2nd interpretation seems to hold water: ***« J’habite à Paris, certes, mais ça veut pas dire pour autant que j’aime cette ville. »***

Comment: If you apply the 1st interpretation here, it will be more like: ***« Le fait que j’habite à Paris, ce n’est pas vraiment ce qui me fait aimer cette ville. (C’est pour une autre raison.) »***

Answer (score 0):

A less literal translation would be:

> L'accent du polonais n'incite pas vraiment à apprendre la langue.

This translation convey clearly a mening of dismay about the Polish accent, which seems to be the case with the original sentence. IMO, the construction:

> Ce n'est pas parce qu'on est attiré par l'accent polonais qu'on se met à apprendre la langue

seems to indicate a more positive attitude about the accent.